# Xuggler generates error message

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, xuggle, xuggler

I was working on creating my first Xuggler media application. I was coding by watching their video on how to create the first media application.

### Code

```
package demo;

import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;

public class GetContainerInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length!=1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no file");
        }
        IContainer container = IContainer.make();
        if(container.open(args[0],IContainer.Type.READ,null)<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open");
        }
    }
}
```

### Error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

### Do I have the dependencies?

Yes, I do! I have all the dependencies. I imported them while creating the project.
Image:
[image]

## What is causing that error and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SLF4J manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html):

```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details.
```

> This warning is printed because no slf4j binding could be found on
>   your class path. The warning will disappear as soon as you add a
>   binding to your class path. Assuming you add **slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar** so
>   that your class path contains: slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
>   slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar ...

Comment: all these dependencies are stored in **E:\xuggler-and-dependencies** so that will be the classpath?

Comment: The name SLF4J stands for Simple Logging **Facade** for Java. I.e. it assumes that there is already a logging implementation in your application. You should have slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar or other in your classpath to enable logging. Please check the link that I provided in the answer.

Comment: Well, Xuggler does not ask for `simple` file. I will still add that to class path

Answer (score 0):

Cause Could be un-availability of dependency jars or version conflicts.

Adding the following jars in the class path worked fine for me:

xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
logback-core-1.0.0.jar
logback-classic-1.0.0.jar